# What is meant by $[x]$ in this case?

Tags: gamma-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm reading a [report](http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~fjmliou/Calculus2/Gamma.pdf) on the *$\space$Gamma function$\space$* and in the first segment it talks about where the following representation of the Gamma function converges:

$$\Gamma(x)= \int^{\infty}_{0} t^{x-1} e^{-t} \space dx$$

On the second page it says:

*"Let $\space x\geq 1 \space$ be any real number. Let $\space [x] \space$ be the largest integer so that$\space [x]\leq x < [x]+1 \space$."*

Is the author referring to the *$\space$floor function*?

Comment: Seems to be the floor function.

Comment: Yes. That's integer part of $x$ or the floor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the author referring to the floor function?

Yes. In fact, this is perhaps still the dominant notation, even though $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is a much nicer notation.

Comment: Ahh I see. I wasn't familiar with $[x]$ being used as the floor function. Thank you.